# Update pivot table filters using date range from 2 cells and name from another cell

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have an Excel dashboard that updates tables and charts when the name and dates are changed in specific cells, but I also need 2 pivot tables to update using these cells too.
My name cell is D2:G2 and my date range cells are From: P2 To: R2

I've tried various solutions found on the net for updating pivot date ranges but none of them work when trying to link them with the name update code.

So far I have:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim PTable As PivotTable
    Dim PField As PivotField
    Dim Str As String

    On Error Resume Next
    If Intersect(Target, Range("D2:G2")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set PTable = Worksheets("Stats").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    Set PField = PTable.PivotFields("BM attendees")
    Str = Target.Text
    PField.ClearAllFilters
    PField.CurrentPage = Str
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I have some working VBA to update one of the pivots when the name is changed, but I need both pivots to update, and also need the dates on both pivots to update based on the date range.
If anyone can help with the VBA to get this working it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Long ago, trying to do what you are intending I couldn't so I started using Slicers, they are easy to filter and you can connect them to multiple pivot tables (if they have the same source data). Try that.

Comment: You need to remove `On Error Resume Next`. This line hides **all** error massages but the errors still occur, you just cannot see the messages. This makes you blind for any errors in the entire procedure. • You might benefit from reading [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling).

Comment: They are filters above the pivot.

Comment: Why are there 3 cells for a date range? Do you have to select min/max date by your own to filter the range between / or do you just need those 3 items in your date filter?

Comment: There are only 2 cells for the date range P2 and R2. (P being the from date and R being the to date) The name is in 3 cells just because I have merged cells to fit the format of the rest of the worksheet. essentially the name could be just D2.

Comment: Did you give my answer a try? If it works fine for you, please consider to mark it as answer as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). If not, don't hesitate to comment below it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for 1 pivottable to demonstrate how to select pivotitems within filters (= `PageFields`) of a pivot table. As you can not set a date range on a pagefield, you need to switch each corresponding pivot item visible or not.

You always have to ensure, that at least 1 pivotitem remains visible.

You also have to ensure, that the given attendee name (in `Target.Text`) corresponds to any pivot item, before you try to switch the currentpage to that attendee.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim PTable As PivotTable
    Dim PField As PivotField
    Dim PItem As PivotItem
    Dim AttendeeName As Range
    Dim DateFrom As Range, DateTo As Range
    Dim AtLeastItemRemainsVisible As Boolean

    Set AttendeeName = ActiveSheet.Range("D2")
    Set DateFrom = ActiveSheet.Range("D2")
    Set DateTo = ActiveSheet.Range("R2")

    Set PTable = Worksheets("Stats").PivotTables(1) ' or ("PivotTable1")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'Application.EnableEvents = False

    ' Select 1 attendee name as single filter page:
    If Not Intersect(Target, AttendeeName) Is Nothing Then
        Set PField = PTable.PageFields(1) ' or ("BM attendees")
        PField.ClearAllFilters
        PField.EnableMultiplePageItems = False
        For Each PItem In PField.PivotItems
            If PItem.Name = Target.Text Then
                PField.CurrentPage = Target.Text
            End If
        Next PItem

    ' select all valid dates between two given dates:
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Union(DateFrom, DateTo)) Is Nothing Then
        Set PField = PTable.PageFields(2)
        PField.ClearAllFilters
        PField.EnableMultiplePageItems = True

        ' at least 1 PivotItem must remain visible:
        AtLeastItemRemainsVisible = False
        For Each PItem In PField.PivotItems
            If CDate(PItem.Name) >= CDate(DateFrom) _
                And CDate(PItem.Name) <= CDate(DateTo) Then
                AtLeastItemRemainsVisible = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next PItem

        If AtLeastItemRemainsVisible Then
            For Each PItem In PField.PivotItems
                PItem.Visible = _
                    CDate(PItem.Name) >= CDate(DateFrom) _
                    And CDate(PItem.Name) <= CDate(DateTo)
            Next PItem
        End If
    End If

    'Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Separate story: I suggest to use a date filter on a corresponding rowfield or columnfield instead of using dates as `PageField`. Be aware that you have to convert date values into strings to use it with such a `PivotFilter`. Here's a general example:

```
Private Sub DateFilter()
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).RowFields(1)
        .ClearAllFilters

        ' between two dates:
        .PivotFilters.Add2 _
            Type:=xlDateBetween, _
            Value1:=CStr(DateSerial(Year(Date) - 1, Month(Date), Day(Date))), _
            Value2:=CStr(Date), _
            WholeDayFilter:=True

        ' another example, please refer to macro recorder for special date ranges:
        .PivotFilters.Add2 _
            Type:=xlDateThisYear

    End With
End Sub
```